# Getting SerializationException around 4:45 pm every day

Tags: java, exception, gwt, serialization

Since 7 to 8 days we are getting com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException for a specific class which already implements Serializable and works totally fine except this time period. Following is the print stack trace of the error

> Blockquote
>   18:03:56.378 500     83B 205ms
>   /getFilterCriteria
>       119.151.4.60 - admin [12/May/2014:05:33:56 -0700] "POST /getFilterCriteria HTTP/1.1" 500 83 "http://8-dot-scm-gpractice.appspot.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36" "8-dot-scm-gpractice.appspot.com" ms=205 cpu_ms=36 cpm_usd=0.000009 instance=00c61b117c504c466bb217aa1c7bdc2ddb49cf77 app_engine_release=1.9.4
>       W 18:03:56.177
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient : Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
>       E 18:03:56.375
>   javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'com.app.scmProject.shared.ProductSetup' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = com.app.scmProject.shared.ProductSetup@b81e3d at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:667) at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126) at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.serialize(Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.java:44) at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:39) at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serializeInstance(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:51) at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serializeInstance(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:28) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:788) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:669) at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:587) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:605) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForSuccess(RPC.java:471) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:563) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166) at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388) at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765) at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152) at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444) at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300) at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441) at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
>
> Blockquote

Comment: Time info is not shown in logs.

Comment: Have you investigated "Type 'com.app.scmProject.shared.ProductSetup' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. "?

Comment: Share the code to analyze it.

Comment: Is there any job that runs at this time in your application daily?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [IsSerializable](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/IsSerializable.html) along with `Serializable`.

For e.g

```
public class ProductSetup implements IsSerializable, Serializable{
    // there must be default no-argument constructor
}
```

Comment: tried with the same. But getting the same exception again.

Comment: Edited the post with time info

Comment: What is `getFilterCriteria()` here? I want to look into code.

Comment: its the @RemoteServiceRelativePath for server side code